# Is there any concept of auto commit in hbase?

Tags: apache, hadoop, hbase, bigdata

I am new to hbase and want to learn more. I just want to know if there is any auto commit concept available in HBASE?

Answer (score 5):

HBase [documentation](https://hbase.apache.org/acid-semantics.html)  it is not an ACID compliant database. However, it does guarantee certain specific properties.
This specification enumerates the ACID properties of HBase.

Their is a concept of [AutoFlush](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/perf.writing.html) in HBase which is similar to autocommit.

How ever If you are using [Apache Phoenix](https://phoenix.apache.org/index.html) for fetching or updating data in HBase, then you can set property `phoenix.connection.autoCommit` to true by default it is false.

Answer (score 0):

Commits come majorly at two places : insert/update(Put in HBase) and delete(Delete in HBase)

Since we are in Big Data environment, the requirements would be different when you are ingesting huge volumes of data.

As metnioned in Documentation, the autoCommit should be set to false - for better performance rather than each record maintained individually. It helps in handling buffers in general and load at region server for HBase.

Delete

HBase does not modify data in place, and so deletes are handled by creating new markers called tombstones. These tombstones, along with the dead values, are cleaned up on major [compactions](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#compaction)

One last word on Phoenix, any layer coming on top of HBase will eventually work based on HBase architecture. Hope this helps in your design